# Identifying useless vertices in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a randomly generated directed graph with 3 types of vertices: input, output, and the rest (I'll call them hidden).

A **useless vertex** is a hidden vertex which:

- can't be reached from an input vertex, **OR**
- can't reach an output vertex.

For example:

- input = yellow/green
- output = blue
- hidden = white
- useless = red border

[image: Sample Graph]

Note that:

- cycles and self-loops are allowed
- the graph may be disjoint
- inputs and output nodes are known (i.e. you can determine what type of node an edge connects to and from)

---

**So what do you call this type of problem? Is there any algorithm for this?**

I'm looking for more information about this. I have a python script which seems to work. I'm just not sure if it will work for all cases since I don't fully understand it myself. It was a mix of DFS, trial-and-error, manual hand-checking, and a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Using DFS/BFS, you can find all vertices reachable from some set $S$ (in your case, the inputs). Reversing the direction of the edges, you can find all vertices which can reach a set $T$ (in your case, the outputs). Take the intersection to find all useful vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n$ and $m$ be the number of vertices and edges of your input graph $G = (V,E)$, respectively.
You can find all useless vertices in time $O(n+m)$.

You can discover the set $S$ all vertices reachable by at least one source in $O(n + m)$ **overall** time.

You do this by either:

- running one visit from each of the input vertices, marking discovered vertices as visited, and taking care of **not** revisiting already visited vertices; or
- adding a dummy "super-source" vertex $s$ with an outgoing edge towards every input vertex in $G$, and then running a visit from $s$.

By using the same technique on the reversed graph $G^R$, you can find the set $T$ of all vertices that are reachable from an output vertex in $G^R$. In other words a vertex $v$ can reach an output vertex in $G$ iff $v \in T$.

The set you are looking for is then $V \setminus (S \cap T)$.

Comment: Uhmm.. A vertex $v$ is defined to be useless if $v$ is not reachable from and input vertex **OR** $v$ cannot reach an output vertex. If at least one of these two conditions happens then $v$ won't be in both $S$ and $T$, i.e., $v \not\in S \cap T$. Therefore $v \in V \setminus (S \cap T)$. On the other hand, if none of the above conditions is true then $v$  is in both $S$ and $T$, i.e., $v \in S cap T$, showing that $v \not\in V \setminus (S \cap T)$.